# Change values when copying records from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code to copy data from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO MyDb.Books (CategoryId, Author, Title)
SELECT 
  CategoryId, Author, Title
FROM MyDbBackup.Books
```

I need to apply the following transformation when copying CategoryId values:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
|     Old CategoryId  |  New CategoryId |
+---------------------+-----------------+
|                  1  |               2 |
|                  2  |               1 |
|                  3  |               3 |
|                  4  |               4 |
|                  5  |               8 |
|                 14  |               6 |
|                 15  |               7 |
|                 18  |               5 |
|                 22  |               9 |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can add a hard-coded `CASE` call or join with a lookup table that maps one ID to another. If there's a formula, you can add it to the SELECT clause

Comment: Is there any formula to convert from old to new categoryId ?

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir No, there is not formula. The mapping is done as I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use case when

```
INSERT INTO MyDb.Books (CategoryId, Author, Title)
SELECT 
  case when CategoryId = 1 then 2
       when CategoryId = 2 then 1
       when CategoryId = 5 then 8
       when CategoryId = 14  then 6
       when CategoryId = 15  then 7
       when CategoryId = 18  then 5
       when CategoryId = 22  then 9
       else cateogoryId end, Author, Title
FROM MyDbBackup.Books
```

or a  less verbose way

```
INSERT INTO MyDb.Books (CategoryId, Author, Title)
SELECT 
  case CategoryId 
       when  1 then 2
       when 2 then 1
       when 5 then 8
       when 14  then 6
       when 15  then 7
       when 18  then 5
       when 22  then 9
       else cateogoryId end, Author, Title
FROM MyDbBackup.Books
```

Comment: @TDP   Yes  is possibile and is less  verbose ..  also set  the column at  the beginning and check for value  ..thanks answer updated  with yoru suggestion too

Comment: Also what is `else cateogory`? Is that a typo and you meant to write `else CategoryId`?

Comment: @RacilHilan  is a typo ..answer  updated . with CategoryId .. else mean that if the value are not remapped  the categoryID for select is the same as is .. thanks for the suggestion  ..

Comment: Yes, I know what it means as I have it in my answer ;). You updated one query and forgot the second one :).

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments by Panagiotis Kanavos, you'll need to use a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE CategoryID WHEN 1 THEN 2
                WHEN 2 THEN 1
                WHEN 5 THEN 8
                WHEN 14 THEN 6
                WHEN 15 THEN 7
                WHEN 18 THEN 5
                WHEN 22 THEN 9
                ELSE CategoryID END
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a lookup table a `join`:

```
select v.newid, b.author, b.title
from MyDbBackup.Books b join
     (values (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 8), (14, 6), (15, 7), (18, 5), (22, 9)
     ) v(oldid, newid)
     on b.CategoryId = v.oldid;
```

An alternative is to use a `case` expression.  However, using the `join` ensures that only the set of books with the old ids is in the result set.  So, it does both the lookup and filtering.

If you don't want the filtering, you can use a `left join` instead of an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no formula, then the conversion must be done one by one:

```
INSERT INTO MyDb.Books (CategoryId, Author, Title)
SELECT CASE CategoryID WHEN 1 THEN 2
                       WHEN 2 THEN 1
                       WHEN 5 THEN 8
                       WHEN 14 THEN 6
                       WHEN 15 THEN 7
                       WHEN 18 THEN 5
                       WHEN 22 THEN 9
                      ELSE CategoryId ID END AS CategoryId
       , Author, Title
FROM MyDbBackup.Books
```